# $(I-T)x=d$ always has non-negative solution $x$ if $d$ non-negative. Why $\rho(T)<1$?

Tags: linear-algebra, mathematical-modeling

This question comes from a model in economy developed by Leontief.

**Definition** If for every non-negative vector $d$, there is a non-negative vector $x$ satisfying $(I-T)x=d$, we say $T$ is feasible.

If for every non-negative vector $v$, there is a non-negative vector $p$ satisfying $(I-T)^{\mathrm{T}}p=v$, we say $T$ is profitable.

**Problem** Prove that if $T$ is feasible (or profitable), then $\rho(T)<1$.

Here $\rho(T)$ stands for spectual radius, i.e., the maximal norm of eigenvalues of $T$.

I wonder where to get start with. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I guess your matrix $T$ is non-negative. If this is the case, you should look into the theory of M-matrices (see, e.g. Berman, Plemmons "Nonnegative matrices in dynamic systems")